# Angular is not loading correctly in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've transfered my Rails project to a DigitalOcean droplet and almost got it working after a lot of errors. But the latest problem I'm facing is that Angular is not working because of rails minimizing it. Or at least that's why I think is the problem.

This is the error I'm facing in the (live) console,

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module movieseat due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
```

I've added `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(mangle: false)` to my production.rb file on the server but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [strict dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection) to eliminate [DI annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) problems prior to minimization.

Or rely on [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) entirely instead ([a wrapper for Rails](https://github.com/kikonen/ngannotate-rails) also exists).

Comment: I've added the Rails Wrapper and compiled my assets, but then when I check the app the gem adds some html to my output. `angular.module("templates").run(["$templateCache",function(e){e.put("angular-app/templates/_search.html","
\n \n \n \n \n
")}]);`

Comment: On my previous comment, this had nothing to do with Angular or the wrapper etc. This is caused by the sprocket gem being downgraded after doing a bundle install/update action. Your advice helpt great in the end. Thanks.